# Parse and edit XML file in PHP

Tags: php, xml, file, xml-parsing

How can I do the following edits to an XML file in PHP. I basically want to keep some elements and write those elements to a new XML file.

So, I know how to open the new file and prepare it for writing and then open the XML file and iterate through it line by line:

```
$lines = fopen("file.xml", "r");
$new = fopen("newFile.xml", "w");
foreach($lines as $line){

    /* operations on each line here */
}
```

I don't want to do operations on each line, but on certain elements in the file.xml.

What I need to do is for each `<doc>` element (everything in between `<doc>` and `</doc>`):

1. `echo "<doc>"` and break to a new line in $new.
2. write everything in between `<title>` and `</title>` including the tags to $new.
3. write everything in between `<url>` and `</url>` including the tags to $new.
4. write everything in between `<abstract>` and `<abstract>` including the tags to $new.
5. `echo "</doc>"` and break to a new line.

and then move on to the next `<doc>` `</doc>` block.

I would greatly appreciate all and any help in learning how to do the above.

Comment: What about using SimpleXML? http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: Can you show an examle of file.xml and newFile.xml?

Comment: @kren470 I hadn't heard of simple xml. Thank you for sharing

Comment: @siot file.xml is like `<doc><title>Title 1</title><url>http://someSite.com/Title1</url><abstract>This is the description of Title 1</abstract><nav><link>Link 1 for Title 1</link><link>Link 2 for Title 1</link></nav></doc><doc><title>Title 2</title><url>http://someSite.com/Title2</url><abstract>This is the description of Title 2</abstract><nav><link>Link 1 for Title 2</link><link>Link 2 for Title 2</link></nav></doc>`

Answer (score 6):

Try doing something with the [*simplexml library*](http://php.net/simplexml) like in the following example:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml"); //load file as SimpleXML object
$newXml = SimpleXMLElement(); // create new SimpleXML object

foreach ($xml->doc as $d){ // change "$xml->doc" to the path to doc in your file
    $doc = $newXml->addChild("doc"); // add <doc></doc>
    $doc->addChild("title", (string)$d->title); //add title child within doc
    $doc->addChild("url", (string)$d->url); //add url child within doc
    $doc->addChild("abstract", (string)$d->abstract); //add abstract child within doc
}
$new = fopen("newFile.xml", "w"); // open new file
fwrite($new, $newXml->asXML()); //write XML to new file using asXML method
fclose($new); // close the new file
```

Hope this helps. You can find the full documentation of simplexml here: http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic and there are many more concrete questions and answers here on Stackoverflow: [simplexml](/questions/tagged/simplexml)

Comment: +1: Short and sound example. I just put some wording around so it's not only the code and leaving some references to the manual.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot! One thing that is confusing me is the comment `// change "$xml->doc" to the path to doc in your file`. Why would I change `$xml->doc`? Right now isn't it getting all `<doc>` elements in $xml or file.xml ? Since this script is in the same dir as file.xml, I shouldn't have to change anything, right?

Comment: Hi Django, I added that comment in case `doc` was a child of something else in your XML file. For example, if your XML looked like `<something><doc>...</doc></something>`, you would have to change `$xml->doc` to `$xml->something->doc`. If `$xml->doc` is correctly getting `<doc>` elements, don't change anything.

Comment: Testing it, simplexml_load_file fails unless file.xml has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` on firts line and a root element surrounding all. I've named `<docs><doc>...</doc><doc>...</doc></docs>`

Comment: @Les Hello. All, I see. No, all the `<doc>` elements are children of a `<feed> element. It doesn't have a doctype / `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` so the file loading fails. Also there isn't a `<root>` element surrounding everything. There is a `<feed>` element surrounding everything. And I can't edit the file.

Comment: @Siot Yes it does fail. Because there isn't a `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` at the beginning of the file. There also isn't a `<root>` element containing everything, but there is a `<feed> element containing everything. The problem is that I can not edit file.xml, I can view it and parse it though.

Comment: @DjangoJhonson well `<feed>` tag as `<xml... ><feed><doc>...</doc>...<doc>...</doc></feed>`can be enough. You can add tags to it loading file as string with `$file = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>". file_get_contents('file.xml');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($file);`

Comment: Alert with the use of SimpleXML constructor [PHP reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you have two easy options for working with XML files. (There are others)

The first has already been pointed out: [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

The second option is [DOM - Document Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

To make life even easier, you can search an XML file with [XPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;    
$doc->load('myXMLFile.xml');

$xPath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// Give me all doc elements inside the XML
$docElements = $xPath->query('doc');

foreach ($docElements as $docElement) {
    // Work your magic here!
}
```