# How to create a basic XML file in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I want a basic `XML` generated in PHP and the file can be saved in a directory and be edited...

This is the structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <user>
      <id> 1254</id>      
      <userName>Melanie Woods</userName>

      <channel> 
         <host>  www.natgeo.org   </host>
         <item>  http://animals.natgeo.com/feed.xml   </item>
         <item>  http://birds.natgeo.com/feed.xml   </item>
      </channel>
     /////....The can add as many <'channels'> as they want....
     /////And as many <'items'>' in the channel as they want
       <channel> 
         <host>  www.bbc.com   </host>
         <item>  http://america.bbc.com/feed.xml   </item>
         <item>  http://asia.bbc.com/feed.xml   </item>
         <item>  http://europe.bbc.com/feed.xml   </item>
         <item>  http://australiue.bbc.com/feed.xml   </item>
      </channel>

   </user>
```

I have tried so many approaches since some hours now and still can't figure out the best approach to achieve this.

The challenge is **how to save the file** and **call it** when the User thinks of *adding* or *removing* an `item` or `channel` form the `XML` file.

Let's say they want to Add:

```
<channel>
<host>www.cnn.com</host>
<item>america.news.cnn.com/fedd.xml</item>
</channel>
```

and they wish to remove:

`<item>  http://asia.bbc.com/feed.xml   </item>` from the `bbc.com`   `<channel>`

How to pull the file and add the new `channel`?

What am trying now is using:

```
<?php

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><user></user>");
$id= $xml->addChild('id');
$username = $xml->addChild('userName');
 for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; ++$i) {
    $channel= $xml->addChild('channel');
    $channel->addChild('host', 'www.bbc.com');
    $channel->addChild('item','http://asia.bbc.com/feed.xml'); 
} /**/

Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($xml->asXML());
?>
```

This works but doesn't save the file and suffers from adding random amount of `items` to random number of `channels` instantaneous.

**EDIT:** One more thing, when ran, this code produces a Single line `XML` file *difficult* to read and **It does not Validate **. 
Validator says:

> Sorry
>
> This feed does not validate.
>
> ```
> line 2, column 0: Undefined root element: user [help]
>
>     <user><id/><userName/><channel><host>www.bbc.com</host><item>http://asia.bbc
> ```
>
> ...

Wish it could produce multiple lines as the sample `XML` above

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php)?

Comment: @MuhammadKashifAbbasi Sure wouldn't mind... Any suggestion on how to achieve something like that??... Thank You!

Comment: try this `$xml->asXML('path/filename.xml');` and for help with DOMDocument look at the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to save you can use `$xml->asXML('path/filename.xml');`

You can have a look at this post to get some help [Using SimpleXML and DOMDocument Together](https://gist.github.com/joshhartman/2289649).

Comment: Sure still can't figure out how to: **call the file when the User thinks of adding or removing an item or channel or items and channels form the XML file.** .... that'll lead somewhere. Thx

Comment: Try these post to help  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331495/parse-and-edit-xml-file-in-php]
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156464/i-want-to-modify-the-existing-data-in-xml-file-using-php]

Comment: I think all Good... Accepting the Answer... You can UpVote the question as well. Thanks!